# How would you find the initial letter with the most occurrences using recursion?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, linked-list

Given a sentence that is spread over a linked list where each item in the list is a word, for example:

Hello -> Everybody -> How -> Are -> You -> Feeling -> |

Given that this list is sorted, eg:

Are -> Everybody -> Feeling -> Hello -> How -> You -> |

How would you write the recursion that will find the initial letter that appears the most in the sentence (in this example the letter H from Hello & How) ?

Comment: How would you do it on paper?

Comment: What makes you think recursion is the best way to approach this problem, or is this an exercise/homework?

Comment: That's the exercise :)

Comment: Please clarify "First letter that appears the most in the sentence".  `o` appears far more than `h`...

Comment: @japreiss Seems it must be the first letters of the words. The only applicable letters are A,E,F,H,H,Y. But that statement is very misleading.

Comment: Any particular language?

Comment: They really should use recursive problems to teach recursive algorithms...

Comment: Changed 'first' to 'initial' to clarify intent of exercise.

Comment: If I understood the question, better phrasing would be `"How would you write a recursion function that will find the letter that appears the most often as the first letter of a word in the sentence"`.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I have update the code to recursion version.

In order to run it you call

```
GetMostLetterRecursion(rootNode , '0', 0, '0', 0)
```

The code itself look like this:

```
public char GetMostLetterRecursion(LinkedListNode<String> node, char currentChar, int currentCount, char maxChar, int maxCount)
{
    if (node == null) return maxChar;

    char c = node.Value[0];
    if (c == currentChar)
    {
        return GetMostLetterRecursion(node.Next, currentChar, currentCount++, maxChar, maxCount);
    }

    if(currentCount > maxCount)
    {
        return GetMostLetterRecursion(node.Next, c, 1, currentChar, currentCount);
    }

    return GetMostLetterRecursion(node.Next, c, 1, maxChar, maxCount);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution 1

Loop over the words, keeping a tally of how many words start with each letter. Return the most popular letter according to the tally (easy if you used a priority queue for the tally).

This takes O(n) time (the number of words) and O(26) memory (the number of letters in alphabet).

### Solution 2

Sort the words alphabetically. Loop over the words. Keep a record of the current letter and its frequency, as well as the most popular letter so far and its frequency. At the end of the loop, that's the most popular letter over the whole list.

This takes O(n log n) time and O(1) memory.

Comment: since the list is sorted, option 2 is `O(n)`. you can see the code in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Keep an array to store the count of occurrences and Go through the linked list once to count it. Finally loop through the array to find the highest one.

Rough sketch in C:

```
int count[26]={0};

While ( head->next != NULL)
{
  count[head->word[0] - 'A']++; // Assuming 'word' is string in each node
  head = head->next;
}

max = count[0];
for (i=0;i<26;i++)
{
  if(max<a[i])
    max = a[i];
}
```

You can modify it to use recursion and handle lower case letters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure recursive implementation in Python.  I haven't tested it, but it should work modulo typos or syntax errors.  I used a Dictionary to store counts, so it will work with Unicode words too.  The problem is split into two functions: one to count the occurrences of each letter, and another to find the maximum recursively.

```py
# returns a dictionary where dict[letter] contains the count of letter
def count_first_letters(words):

    def count_first_letters_rec(words, count_so_far):

        if len(words) == 0:
            return count_so_far

        first_letter = words[0][0]

        # could use defaultdict but this is an exercise :)
        try:
            count_so_far[first_letter] += 1
        except KeyError:
            count_so_far[first_letter] = 1

        # recursive call
        return count_first_letters_rec(words[1:], count_so_far)

    return count_first_letters(words, {})


# takes a list of (item, count) pairs and returns the item with largest count.
def argmax(item_count_pairs):

    def argmax_rec(item_count_pairs, max_so_far, argmax_so_far):

        if len(item_count_pairs) == 0:
            return argmax_so_far

        item, count = item_count_pairs[0]

        if count > max_so_far:
            max_so_far = count
            argmax_so_far = item

        # recursive call
        return argmax_rec(item_count_pairs[1:], max_so_far, argmax_so_far)

    return argmax_rec(item_count_pairs, 0, None)


def most_common_first_letter(words);

    counts = count_first_letters(words)

    # this returns a dictionary, but we need to convert to
    # a list of (key, value) tuples because recursively iterating
    # over a dictionary is not so easy

    kvpairs = counts.items()
    # counts.iteritems() for Python 2

    return argmax(kvpairs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an array with the length of 26 (as English letters, so index 1 is for 'a' and 2 for 'b' and so on. ). Each time a letter occurs, I increment it's value in the array. if the value becomes more than max amount, then I update the max and take that letter as most occurred one.then I call the method for the next node.

This is the code in Java:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class MostOccurance {
    char mostOccured;
    int maxOccurance;
    LinkedList<String> list= new LinkedList<String>();
    int[] letters= new int[26];


 public void start(){
     findMostOccuredChar( 0, '0', 0);
 }

 public char findMostOccuredChar ( int node, char most, int max){
     if(node>=list.size())
         return most;
     String string=list.get(node);
     if (string.charAt(0)== most)
         {max++;
         letters[Character.getNumericValue(most)-10]++; 
         }
     else{
         letters[Character.getNumericValue(most)-10]++;
         if (letters[Character.getNumericValue(most)-10]++>max){
             max=letters[Character.getNumericValue(most)-10];
             most=string.charAt(0);
         }
     }
     findMostOccuredChar( node++, most, max);

     return most;
      }


  }
```

of course, you have to add each word to your link list. I didn't do that, because I was just showing an example.